# How can I make this open arc in Sketch?

Tags: vector, shapes, sketch-app

How can I make like this shape in Sketch3 App? [image]

Answer (score 2):

Let's start from oval with no fill:
[image]

Select Edit mode:
[image]

Then choose from menu: **Layer -> Paths -> Scissors**
[image]

Hover over left upper part of the oval, it will be dashed:
[image]

Left click on it, you will get the following result:
[image]

To make the endings rounded select gear icon on border part and select rounded ends:
[image]

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

**To open up the circle's stroke:**

Draw a circle, double-click it, click "Open path" in the sidebar (right below the alignment buttons).

**To get the rounded ends:**

Click the "Gear" button in the "Borders" section of the sidebar. In the "Ends" button group, choose the rounded one.